# Arthropod tag - rename and use

Tags: discussion, tags

While trying to tag [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58192/what-are-these-eggs-location-india) question which essentially asks for possible arthropods laying such stalked eggs I found two tags [arthropod](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arthropod) and [entomology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entomology).

Three questions are tagged [arthropod](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arthropod) and there are 467 questions with tag [entomology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entomology).

I did a surface browsing and found some [millipede questions](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bentomology%5D%20millipede) (Non-insects) tagged entomology (study of Insecta) and not Arthropod. I have a feeling that there may be general questions about arthropods too that have the entomology tag because the term *insect* is loosely used to mean *'any insect or insect like invertebrate.'* <sub>[(Dictionary)](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bug)</sub>

I wonder if I should edit [arthropod](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arthropod) into [Arthropodology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropodology) and then the tag can be useful for tagging questions that are in general about arthropods and questions about Carcinology (the study of crustaceans) and Myriapodology (the study of centipedes, millipedes, and other myriapods) as we don't have tags for these subfields yet.

If there's no counter-argument in a week I will rename the arthropod tag and also elaborate the entomology tag.

Comment: Arthropodology sounds funny; arthropod seems fine.

Comment: It did sound funny to me too. I wonder if any expert could clarify if it is [still](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Arthropodology&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CArthropodology%3B%2Cc0) a standard term for 'the study of arthropods'.

Comment: I agree with @WYSIWYG: Arthropodology sounds goofy and [tag:arthropod] should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It stands arthropod now after a couple of [edits](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/58402/revisions).

Comment: The fastest way to drive a acarologist *insane* is to refer to ticks as insects. While this is fun, it does seem a bit cruel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of edits which was initiated by [another 'Homo sapiens'](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/19099/another-homo-sapien) the two tags stand like this now :

- [arthropod](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arthropod)
- [entomology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entomology)

Answer (score 1):

Though arthropod and arthropodology are grammatically not same; as a "tag"  the both ( i.e. tag [arthropod](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arthropod) and tag [arthropodology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arthropodology)) the both will work same.

Now if someone do not use the [arthropod](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arthropod) tag for a non-insect arthropod, instead choose the wrong tag [entomology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entomology) (that should be used for insects, ie a subgroup of arthropod) only, the problem is not of the tag. It is the users' ignorance. (however the ignorance is no wrong... no-one of us is omniscient)

Though using the term "arthropodology" may be one solution (because along with  entomology; another word ending with "logy" would declare "I am another logy; I am not exactly same as entomology"). But people can still do the same mistake, because entomology is a fairly common English word (even often appear in daily newspaper), and there could be peoples who have listen about "entomology deals with various bugs" but not familiar with difference of entomology (and insect) with arthropodology (and arthropods).

The best way to recover it; is whenever we found such wrongly-labelled question, where a non-insect arthropod has been labelled with [entomology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/entomology);  we need to edit/ suggest-edit to replace the tag with [arthropod](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arthropod), with a comment that why the edit has been done. (A sample as follows):

> Entomology means the study about [insects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect), a sub-group of [arthropods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropod) only. Since the above question is about an arthropod but not an insect; a more general tag [arthropod](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arthropod) has been suggested.

Sample Template:

> `Entomology means the study about [insects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect), a sub-group of [arthropods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthropod) only. Since the above question is about an arthropod but not an insect; a more general tag [tag:arthropod] has been suggested.`

Once the users become aware about this problem (and also while browsing through  collection of properly-labelled question people will become more aware about labelling correctly)